# A complex configuration. How can I get my web server's browser to access a web site served from the same server?

Tags: server, apache2, nginx, reverse-proxy

Server is setup with the full desktop install of Kubuntu Linux 18.04LTS.  I Nginx, and Apache2 installed.  I also have Gogs installed.  And I have 4 cert's from Let's Encrypt installed.

From a web browser on any of the computers on my LAN (and because I've edited my HOSTS file on them), I can get to any of the 4 web sites on my server using i.e.  , , ,

where Domain1 and Domain 2 are served from the Apache2, reverse-proxied from Nginx.
Domain3 and Domain4 are served directly from Nginx, with Domain 4 actually serving up the Gogs service.  The MyEncrypt stuff all goes through Nginx.  It seems to all be working well, except that I can't access any of these 4 domains from the browser on my server.  I realize having a browser on a server is a bit unusual, and it is perhaps not a major problem, but shouldn't there be some way to make it work?  All I get are timeout errors from it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem I was having, and as usual it turtned out to be something considerably simpler than I'd anticipated.  It turns out I had configured the ethernet port incorrectly in Kubuntu's System Settings > Connections GUI.  I discovered the problem when I had some issues with apt failing.

The correct settings I needed were:
{

```
Select IPv4 tab.
Set Method: Manual
DNS Servers: 192.168.0.1
Search Domains 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
DHCP Client ID: (blank)
Address: 192.168.0.20 (static address on LAN)
Netmask 255.255.255.0
Gateway 192.168.0.1
```

}

I found my mistake when I looked at how I had setup a different server on my LAN that was also using Kubuntu 18.04 LTS, and it was working.  I've now made a hardcopy of the screenshot so I have a handy reference for the future.